# To each injective function there exists a surjective such that $f \circ g =\operatorname{Id}_X$

Tags: proof-verification, set-theory

So I learned that to each surjective function exists an injective function. I wanted to prove the other direction since it sounded reasonable.
[image: Let g be an injective function]

Then there should exist a surjective function f such that $fog = \operatorname{Id}_X$
[image: Claim (F)]
For each injective function $g: X  \to Y$, there exists a surjective function $f: Y\to X$ such that $f∘g = \operatorname{Id}_X$ applies.

Proof (Axiom of choice)

Consider for each $y∈g(X)$ the set $X_y := \{x∈X: g(x) = y\} $

Since $g$ is a function, there follows that  $X_y , g(X) ≠ ∅$.
For all $y: X_y≠∅$ since g is a function.

The axiom of choice says there exists a function $f : g(X) \to \bigcup\limits_{y∈g(x)} (X_y),  =X,\;g(x) ⊂ Y$, thus it follows that $f: Y \to X$ with $f(y) ∈ X_y\; ∀y$  *since $g$ is injective.

So is this a correct proof and a correct claim? 
I just went with my gut intuition

Comment: @Lukas Kofler I don't know but I by mistake rejected your edit. I wanted to click Accept.

Comment: A picture proof can get the main idea but miss some details. (+1)

Comment: Isn't the picture for the f is incorrect if we just exclude the $Y_7$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the Axiom of Choice for the wrong direction.

If we have an injective $g:X\to Y$, then assuming $X$ is non-empty we can construct a surjective $f:Y\to X$ without Choice the following way:

> Pick a distinguished element $x_0\in X$. Now take an arbitrary $y\in Y$. If there is an $x\in X$ such that $g(x) = y$, then $f(y) = x$ (this $x$ is unique by injectivity, so this is well-defined). If there is no such $x$, then $f(y) = x_0$.

On the other hand, if we have a surjective $f:Y\to X$, then we need Choice. We can construct an injective $g:X\to Y$ the following way:

> Take an arbitrary $x\in X$, and look at the set $f^{-1}(\{x\})$. This set is non-empty, so we can pick a $y$ in it. Set $g(x) = y$. This can be done for any $x\in X$, and two distinct $x$ will necessarily result in two distinct $y$, so our $g$ is injective. However, we need the Axiom of Choice in order to guarantee that we can do this for all $x\in X$ simultaneously, and stitch together the results into an actual function $g$.

Comment: (N.B.: If $X$ is non-empty or $Y$ is empty.)

Comment: @MeesdeVries Yes. That is an important assumption. There must exist functions $Y\to X$.

Comment: For the first part, what does taking this special X o ∈ X do? I fail to see why it is relevant. Since you are taking any y ∈ Y and claiming if ∃ x ∈ X : g ( x ) = y ⇒ f ( y ) = x Second of all can one write/say/claim f -1 ( { x } ) . I thought an inverse function exists only for a bijective function? But f is surjective. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: And please excuse my ignorance, but I am really having a hard time distinguishing why in the first case we do not need the axiom but in the second case we do Is it maybe because in the second case the surjective function could have multiple elements building to the same picture Example f ( x ) = y 1 ^ f ( x 2 ) = y 1 Thus you need the axiom in order to CHOOSE?

Comment: @MadSpaceMemer For the first part, the special $x_0$ is where we send all the $y$ that aren't in the image of $g$. In your drawing, for instance, we need to send $y_7$ _somewhere_. And if there is a $y_8$, we need to send that somewhere too. Sending them all to the same element means we can get away with making a single choice, and therefore we do not need Choice. Also, what I meant by $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is "The set of all $y\in Y$ such that $f(y) = x$". It's kindof like an inverse, but it exists for any function and maps subsets to subsets instead of elements to elements.

Comment: As for why we need Choice in the second case and not the first, the Axiom of Choice is, a little informally, needed whenever you need to make (potentially) infinitely many choices, and still be certain that you can have an end result. For the first case, i made a single choice, and everything else was constructed directly. For the second case, I need to make a choice for _every single_ $x\in X$, and I need to collect all the choices made into a single function. That's where Choice comes in.

Comment: You are amazing !! Thanks!!!